# Ошибка при удалении файла в Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь удалить файлы(фотографии, видео, аудио), приложение вылетает, ему не нравится мой Uri.

Код:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            val collection: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()

            for (i in 0 until Params.dataListPath.size) {
                collection.add(Params.dataListPath[i].file.path.toUri())
                Log.d(TAG, "onShowDialogConfirmDelete: " + collection[i].path)
            }

            val  pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(requireActivity().contentResolver, collection).intentSender

            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent, 100, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
}
```

logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be referenced by specific ID
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:732)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:2433)
        at android.provider.MediaStore.createRequest(MediaStore.java:834)
        at android.provider.MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(MediaStore.java:997)
        at com.test.cleanerapp.duplicate_files.view.fragment.DuplicateFindFragment.onShowDialogConfirmDelete(DuplicateFindFragment.kt:119)
```

Comment: На а как вы эти `Uri` составляете и как они выглядят мы должны в хрустальном шаре посмотреть?

Comment: Ну а как получают путь к файлу, наверное через File. Выглядят примерно так - /storage/emulated/0/Download/1616012061157.jpg

Comment: Media Uri и путь к файлу не имеют ничего общего. Если у вас есть прямой доступ к ФС, то через File и удаляйте. Если нет то вам нужно добыть их Uri из MediaStorage. И это абсолютно разные истории. И, если не ошибаюсь, через MediaStorage можно удалить только те файлы, которые созданы вашим приложением, а значит их Uri у вас должны быть

Comment: Необязательно через MediaStore только свои файлы удалять, просто если удалять "чужой" файл то необходимо запрашиавать разрешение( в API 30+) собственно что и хочу сделать

Answer (score 1):

Все что надо было - это из File.path получить приемлемый путь для MediaStore. Если кому надо будет:

Метод, который делает необходимое преобразование:

```
private fun onGetFilePathToMediaID(songPath: String, context: Context): Long {
        var id: Long = 0
        val cr: ContentResolver = context.getContentResolver()
        val uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
        val selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(songPath)
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
        val sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
        val cursor: Cursor? = cr.query(uri, projection, "$selection=?", selectionArgs, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val idIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
                id = cursor.getString(idIndex).toLong()
            }
        }
        return id
    }
```

Соотвественно мой код изменился следующим образом:

```
val collectionPhoto: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()
        val collectionVideo: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()
        val collectionAudio: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()

        var mediaID: Long = 0

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            for (i in 0 until Params.dataListPath.size) {
                mediaID = onGetFilePathToMediaID(Params.dataListPath[i].file.absolutePath, requireActivity())
                when (Params.dataListPath[i].typeFile) {
                    FileType.VIDEO -> {
                        val uriVideo = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("external"), mediaID)
                        collectionVideo.add(uriVideo)
                    }
                    FileType.PHOTO -> {
                        val uriPhoto = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external"), mediaID)
                        collectionPhoto.add(uriPhoto)
                    }
                    FileType.AUDIO -> {
                        val uriAudio = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external"), mediaID)
                        collectionAudio.add(uriAudio)
                    }
                }
            }

            val  pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(requireActivity().contentResolver, collectionPhoto).intentSender
            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent, 100, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
        }
```

Comment: да это известный костыль, не используйте его а делаете согласно документации